# End of file detected on input -- Help please

Tags: java, file

I tried submitting this and an error pops up saying **** END OF FILE detected on input -- EXIT ****.

I cant figure out what this means, just to be clear I am trying to set up a system so that data is input on a loop unless the value is 0. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int SN = 1;
        while ( SN != 0)
        {
            System.out.print("#SN : " );
            SN = BIO.getInt();
            System.out.print("#CW : " );
            int CW = BIO.getInt();
            System.out.print("#EX : " );
            int EX = BIO.getInt();
            double Mark = CW + EX;
            System.out.printf("SN= " + SN + "EX= " + EX + "CW= " + CW + "Mark= " + "%6.1f", (double) Mark / 2      );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the BIO code:

```
class BIO
{
  private static final int EOF  = -1;
  private static final int NONE = -2;
  private static int nextChar = NONE;
  private static boolean EOFdetected = false;

  public static String getLineBASE()
  {
    String line = "";                                 // Line read 
    int    ch;                                        // Read ch 

    try
    {
      ch = System.in.read();                          // No next char 

      if ( ch == EOF ) 
      {
        System.out.println("**** END OF FILE " + 
                           "detected on input -- EXIT ****" );
        System.exit(-1);
      }
      while( ch != '\n'  )                            // Read loop 
      {
        if ( ch == EOF )
        {
          EOFdetected = true;
          return line;                                //  exit 
        }
        line = line + (char) ch;                      //  form line 
        ch = System.in.read();                        //  next ch 
      }
      return line;                                    // return line 
    }
    catch( IOException exp )                          // Problem 
    {
      System.exit(-1);                                // Exit ** 
    }
    return "";                                        // Blank line 
  }

 public static String getLine()
  {
    String line = getLineBASE();                      // Read line 
    //System.out.println( line ); 
    return line;
  }


  public static String getString()
  {
    String line = getLine();                          // Read line 
    return line.trim();
  }

  public static double getDouble()
  {
    String res = getLine();                           // Read line 
    double value = 0.0;                               // 
    try
    {
      value = Double.parseDouble( res.trim() );       // Convert 
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException ex )                // Problem 
    {                                                 //  ignore 
    }
    return value;                                     // return 
  }

  public static int getInt()
  {
    String res = getLine();                           // Read line 
    int value = 0;                                    // 
    try
    {
      value = Integer.parseInt( res.trim() );         // Convert 
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException ex )                // Problem 
    {                                                 //  ignore 
    }
    return value;                                     // return 
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the BIO class? Also do you have a stacktrace for the error you're getting?

Comment: Hey guys i'm not able to fit the whole code in here

Comment: Adam, **edit your question**, don't post code in comment!

Comment: @MikeDeck the BIO code is up. sorry about that

Comment: that's not the entire `BIO` class, is it?  I don't see where `BIO.getInt()` is defined.

Comment: @AdamByrne looks like you didn't put the whole class in your edit. I don't see the `getInt()` implementation which is really the method we need to see. Also it looks like you're missing the closing brace for the class which leads me to believe you didn't paste the whole thing.

Comment: @MikeDeck sorry yeah you were right. Its now all there

Comment: Why are you surprised that your own error message is displayed under the condition that you programmed it to be displayed under? And incidentially why are you reinventing `readLine()`? It already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try
{
  ch = System.in.read();  //reads from keyboard.

  if ( ch == EOF ) 
  {
    System.out.println("**** END OF FILE " + 
                       "detected on input -- EXIT ****" );
    System.exit(-1);
  }
}
```

This snippet reads in input from the keyboard. If you want to read stuff from a file (Which I assume you are, since there is an EOF) look up the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. If this is not what you wanted, my apologies, I am only making assumptions.